# SQL Server: display whole column only if substring found

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-like

Working with SQL Sever 2016. I am constrained by the fact we cannot create functions or stored procedures. I am trying to find %word% in many columns across a table (75). Right now, I have a very large clump of

```
and (fieldname1 like %word%
     or fieldname2 like %word%
     or fieldname3 like %word%) etc.
```

While cumbersome, this does provide me the correct results. However:

1. I am looking to simplify this and
2. in the `select`, I want to display the whole column if and only if it finds `%word%` (or even just the column name would work)

Thank you in advance for any thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--...slow...
declare @searchfor varchar(100) = '23';

select @searchfor as [thevalue], 
    thexml.query('for $a in (/*[contains(upper-case(.), upper-case(sql:variable("@searchfor")))]) 
    return concat(local-name($a[1]), ",")').value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as [appears_in_columns],
    *
from
(
select *, (select o.* for xml path(''), type) as thexml
from sys.all_objects as o --table goes here
) as src
where thexml.exist('/*[contains(upper-case(.), upper-case(sql:variable("@searchfor")))]') = 1;
```

Comment: This seems to get close, thank you. Can you explain the xml.query part?

Comment: what is the performance diff between the "large clump" and the xml/xquery approach? (is an explanation needed? most likely you've already dissected it)

Answer (score 0):

One option uses `cross apply` to unpivot the table and then search:

```
select v.*
from mytable t
cross apply (values 
    ('fieldname1', fieldname1), 
    ('fieldname2', fieldname2),
    ('fieldname3', fieldname3)
) v(fieldname, fieldvalue)
where v.fieldvalue like '%word%'
```

Note that if more than one column contains the search word, you will get several rows in the resultset. I am unsure how you want to handle this use case (there are options).

Comment: Interesting. Thank you kindly. I'm having issues joining to this. The table contains a unique identifier that wouldn't be in the listed values that'd I want to search and display. Would you have an idea? I'm not as concerned with the multiple rows.

Comment: @rSem: you can just add any column from `mytable` that you like to the  `select` clause: `select t.id, v.* from ...`

Comment: I did try that:

left join 
(
select 
t.uniqueID
,v.*
from dbo.sometable t
cross apply (values 
   ('field1',f1),
('field2',f2),
('field3',f3),
) v(fieldname, fieldvalue)
where v.fieldvalue like '%' + @prmSearch + '%'
)somealias
on somealias.uniqueID = anothertablealias.uniqueID      

...

--but later when i try to use those columns in the outer query in the predicate

or lower( somealias.f1) like '%' + variable + '%'
or lower( somealias.f2) like '%' + variable + '%'       

--i get unrecognized column errors

Comment: @rSem: I don't know how you are trying to use the query. But be aware that it `v`'s columns are called `fieldname` and `fieldvalue`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(id) ObjectName , [Text]  
FROM syscomments 
WHERE TEXT LIKE '%word%'
```

Comment: Thank you.This looks like it is returning system comments but not the fields from the table